# Hibernate-Search: How to search dates?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private long id;

 @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 20)
 private String userName;

 @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 10)
 private String password;

 @Column(name = "Date", nullable = false )
 private Date date;
}
```

How can I select the records which have the date between

- [now  |   now-x hours]
- [now  |   now-x days]
- [now  |   now-x months]
- [now  |   now-x years]

Answer (score 0):

the same way as with the other fields: <= >= or between etc

you can use commons-lang / DateUtils to modify the date.